# Cylinder or tubes with different radius

Tags: plotting

I'm trying to generate a set of cylinders/tubes with different radii and colours.

In particular,  I have this graph: `{1 -> 2, 2 -> 3, 3 -> 4, 4 -> 5, 5 -> 1}` with the following vertexes `{0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 10}, {10, 0, 10}, {10, 10, 
    0}, {5, 15, 10}`.

Furthermore, I have a list of values `b = {1, 3, 0.5, -1, -2}` and I want to plot 5 tubes (one for each value) with a specified radius `r1` if the related element of `b` is greater than zero, and `r2` if it is <0. How can I do this? Also, I want to plot these tubes with a range of colours consistent with the vector `b` and `a` framed bar legend. Thanks.

```
q = {1, 3, 0.5, -1, -2};
Grafo = Graph[{1 <-> 2, 2 <-> 3, 3 <-> 4, 4 <-> 5, 5 <-> 1}, 
EdgeWeight -> q];
el = EdgeList[Grafo];
edgestylea = 
Thread[el -> (Directive[
ColorData[{"TemperatureMap", {Min[q], Max[q]}}][#]] & /@ q)];
Legended[Graph3D[Grafo, EdgeStyle -> edgestylea, 
EdgeShapeFunction -> ({ColorFunction -> (ColorData[
"TemperatureMap", #] & /@ q), 
Cylinder[#, If[# < 0, 0.1, 0.5] & /@ q]} &), 
VertexLabels -> "Name", 
VertexShapeFunction -> ({Yellow, Sphere[#, 1]} &), 
VertexCoordinates -> {{0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 10}, {10, 0, 10}, {10, 10, 
0}, {5, 15, 10}}, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0, 0}, Axes -> True, 
Ticks -> Automatic, 
PlotLabel -> 
Style[Framed["Tensegrity", RoundingRadius -> 10], 14, Black, 
FontFamily -> "Times New Roman"], AxesLabel -> {x, y, z}, 
LabelStyle -> {FontFamily -> "Times New Roman"}], 
Framed[BarLegend[{"TemperatureMap", {Min[q], Max[q]}}, 
LegendLabel -> "Internal force" , 
LabelStyle -> {FontFamily -> "Times New Roman"}], 
RoundingRadius -> 10, FrameStyle -> GrayLevel[.5]]]
```

In my code, tubes with different radii consistent with b don't work! Someone can help me?

Comment: What about the axes of these cylinders?

Comment: I have this graph {1 [DirectedEdge] 2, 2 [DirectedEdge] 3, 3 [DirectedEdge] 4,4 [DirectedEdge] 5,5 [DirectedEdge] 6} with the following vertexes {0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 10}, {10, 0, 10}, {10, 10, 0},{10, 10, 10},{10, 10, 20}.

Comment: You should've mentioned that to begin with. Please edit your question to include this information.

Comment: Sorry. I have this graph:
{1 [DirectedEdge] 2, 2 [DirectedEdge] 3, 3 [DirectedEdge] 4,4 [DirectedEdge] 5,5 [DirectedEdge] 6} with the following vertexes {0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 10}, {10, 0, 10}, {10, 10, 0},{10, 10, 10},{10, 10, 20}. I have a list of values b={1,3,0.5,-1,-2} and I want to plot 5 tubes (one for each value) with a specified radius r1 if the related element of b is greater than zero, and r2 if it is <0. How can I do this? Also, I want to plot the tubes with a range of colours consistent with the vector b and a framed bar legend. Thanks

Comment: Please use the "edit" button at the bottom of your post, or click on [this link](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/posts/143353/edit), to add information to your post, instead of keeping it in the comments.

Comment: can someone help me please?

Answer (score 1):

```
b = {1, 3, 0.5, -1, -2};

SeedRandom[3];

data = Transpose[
   {Partition[RandomReal[1, {6, 3}], 2, 1], b}];

Graphics3D[Tube[#[[1]], If[#[[2]] < 0, 0.025, 0.05]] & /@ data]
```

[image]

or

```
r[x_] = Piecewise[{{0.025, x < 0}}, 0.05];

Graphics3D[Tube[#[[1]], r[#[[2]]]] & /@ data]
```

**EDIT:**

```
vertices = {{0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 10}, {10, 0, 10}, {10, 10, 0}, {10, 10, 
    10}, {10, 10, 20}};

Graphics3D[{Red, Arrowheads[0.075],
  Arrow[Tube[#[[1]], If[#[[2]] < 0, 0.1, 0.25]]] & /@ 
   Transpose[{Partition[vertices, 2, 1], b}]},
 Boxed -> False]
```

[image]

Comment: I have this graph {1 \[DirectedEdge] 2, 2 \[DirectedEdge] 3, 3 \[DirectedEdge] 4,4 \[DirectedEdge] 5,5 \[DirectedEdge] 6} with the following vertexes
{0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 10}, {10, 0, 10}, {10, 10, 0},{10, 10, 10},{10, 10, 20}.